# Passing a view as a dialog with codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui-dialog

What i would like to do, is instead of loading up a separate page to input data into a database, i would like to pop open a dialog, and upon submission, it would add data to the database and refresh  the page.

For example: I'm on the index page and want to add another entry to a datagrid. I would click a button that adds a new entry. A dialog pops up, i add information into it, and hit submit. It would then refresh and remain on the index page.

This is what i currently have, but it doesn't do anything right now.

**Index page:**

```
<div id="createEntry">
   <button>Create new item</button>
</div>

$("button")
    .button().click(function(){
        $.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>test/create', function(response){
            $('#dialog').html(response);
        });
    });
```

**Create page**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Create new test case">

   <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'test/create') ?>
    <label for="title">Title</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="title" /><br />

   <label for="something">Something</label><br />
   <textarea name="something"></textarea><br />

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create" /> 
</div>

<script>
    $("#dialog").dialog();
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function create()
{
    //...
    //some code here for validation
    //
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $var = $this->load->view('test/create', '', TRUE);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else
    {
        //adds to db
        $this->test_model->set();
    }
}
```

I feel like i'm close. There's just something i'm missing

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $config['global_xss_filtering']  is true or false ?

Comment: `$config['global_xss_filtering']` is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer. I needed a `<div id="dialog">` on the index page.